# What subordinate clauses are there here?

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses

1) Am I right to divide these senteces into clauses like this?

2) What about their types(subject, predicative, object)?

> 1. It’s odd **(main clause)** / how it hurts/ at these times/ not to be part of your proper family **(predicative)**.
> 2. It was only then **(main clause)** / that I realized **(predicative)** / that she was travelling too **(subject)**.
> 3. What I want to know **(predicative)** /  is / when you’re going to get married **(subject)**

In the 1st one we can change the order like:
***Not to be part of your proper family hurts*** and it is odd - so that must be a subject, right?

What about the 2nd, some would call **"that I realized"** - a relative clause, but I don't know what it is. It's not even in my lecture material. Is it the same as an **appositive (content) clause**?

This source may give you an idea of what clauses are according to Russian grammarians: (http://bookre.org/reader?file=627767&pg=303)

Just help me to define types of clauses, according to the source I gave.

Answer (score 3):

> It’s odd (main clause) how it hurts at these times not to be part of your proper family (2.main clause).

*it*-subject (pronominal it); *is odd..family*-predicate; *not to be part of your proper family* is a subject of this subordinate clause.
>

> It was only then (main clause) / that I realized that she was travelling too.(subordinate clause, predicative)

You can say *Only then (adverbial modifier of time) I realized that she was travelling too*(relative clause functioning as object). *it* is a subject called *preparatory it*)
>

> What I want to know is (1.main clause, predicative) / when you’re going to get married (2.main clause, object)

*I*- is a subject, because you can say

> *When you are going to get married is what I want to know*.

This sentence *when you're...married* refers to *what* and it is subordinate sentence functioning as direct object.

Answer (score 1):

I'd parse the first sentence

> It’s odd, how it hurts at these times not to be part of your proper
>   family.

like this:

{How it hurts at these times not to be part of your proper family} is the subject phrase, apposite {It}, a dummy subject. What is being predicated of that subject? {(it) is odd}

Let's do some recursion and drill down into the subject phrase:

A negated infinitive clause {not to be part of your proper family} is the subject of the verb {hurts}; the subject is again apposite another dummy subject {it}; the verb has adverbial modifiers {how} and {at these times}.